# Show this set is closed, $S= \{f \in B([a,b]): 0 \le f \le 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the set (where $B([a,b])$ is the set of all bounded real valued functions on $[a,b]$) $$S=\{f \in B([a,b]): 0\le f \le 1\}$$
Show $S$ is closed.

Let $f$ be a limit point of $S$ then there exists a sequence $(f_n) \subset S$ with limit $f$.

So, $$0 \le f_n \le 1$$

I don't know what to do from here to show $f \in S$, can anyone help?

After hints:

Take $x \in [a,b]$, $$|f(x)-f_n(x)| \le ||f-f_n|| \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$

So $$f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x) \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$

I am trying to obtain $0 \le f(x) \le 1$ but I can't see how to reach it, can I simply say from this that $0\le f(x) \le 1$? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hint: $f = f_n + f - f_n \le 1 + \|f-f_n\|$.

Comment: Which topology do you consider on $B([a,b])$?

Comment: @user251257 I see $d(f,f_n)$ goes to zero as $n$ tends to infinity, so $lim f_n (x) = f(x)$ but I just can't seem to get to $0 \le f \le 1$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't know what that even means, I have just started the topic of closed sets and limit points if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is the closed ball of radius $1/2$ centred at the constant function $1/2$.

Comment: Thanks, I now know the set is definitely closed but I struggle with the proof